# How to make a table read/writes faster?

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds

I am using AWS RDS DB in my web application. The problem is a table which has millions of rows in it and the number of reads/writes per second on the table are huge. This happens even though I have DB replication, caching and queueing (to write data) mechanism in place.

Becuase of the indexes and the size of the table, the inserts are becoming slower. Sharding/partitioning would also not help as there is not a single column with which table can be partitioned. Is there any other way I can improve write frequency per second to the table?

Comment: `SHOW CREATE TABLE MY_TAB\G`. What is your definition of "huge"? What is your AWS machine spec?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are hundreds of answers.

- Get rid of redundant indexes.  [Index cookbook](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql)
- Batch the `INSERTs`
- Build "summary tables" (very useful in DW type apps).  [Summary tables](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables)
- Get a bigger AWS instance
- With very rare exceptions Partitioning does *not* speed up anything.  [Partition blog](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint)
- Sharding is useful only if the data can be split is certain ways; meanwhile it slows down other operations.
- AWS does a decent job of setting the tunable `VARIABLES`, so there is not likely to be any benefit in further tuning them.  [Further analysis](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis)
- Turn on the slowlog to find out which queries are the 'worst'.  [Slowlog](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis)
- If possible, avoid using GUIDs/UUIDs.  [UUIDs don't scale](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/uuid)
- Don't do pagination via `OFFSET`.  [Pagination blog](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pagination)

Please provide some clues of what the application is about.  Include `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and sample `INSERTs` and `SELECTs`.

Comment: I added two more.

Comment: And I managed to get my "too broad" Answer posted before the Question got put on hold for being "too broad".  Start a new Question if you want to talk specifics.